# why is not adviced to change table structure programatically?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Generally, application user is not supposed to have DDL rights.
I was searching for the reason for this but could not find anything.

I could understand that there might be locking issues with this kind of design but wanted to read more details on the same.

Could anyone explain or point me to any article around this please ?

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"never use DDL in businesses logic" -  It is a rule of thumb for Oracle.

- DDL does not scale
- DDL require exclusive locks, and might die on DDL execution timeout
- DDL can not be rolled back (does not support transactions)
- DDL invalidates execution plans
- DDL might require recompilation of PL/SQL code

You usually do not want this to happen during business hours.

Answer (score 4):

> Generally, application user is not supposed to have DDL rights. I was searching for the reason for this but could not find anything.

Creating/Altering table is not done on the fly. You create them once, and only manipulate the data via application(using PL/SQL stored objects). The database design is not supposed to change frequently i.e. an **application user** is not supposed to add/alter/drop the database objects. It should be done by a **database user**(with required privilege/role) and not application user.

Application should only do **DML** and not **DDL**. The application users should only be able to manipulate the data and should not manipulate the objects itself that stores the data.

Imagine a database with multiple users, and each user doing a DDL operation without the knowledge/consent of other users. How would other users be able to work? What about the functionality based on the database design? What about the application logic based on the database design? Every production system has a release calender for such changes, and it is something which is not supposed to be done frequently.

Comment: IMHO, an application shouldn't even do DML; it should all be done through stored procedures that the application account has the necessary privs to run. That way, if there was a need to do DDL (eg. to truncate a GTT or create an external table on the fly - rare, but sometimes necessary), it's the object owning schema that does the work, and it should already have the necessary privleges. Meanwhile, in the real world... *{;-)

Comment: Ah! I should have been more clear while saying application should do only DML, I actually meant by application via PL/SQL objects. But, I have also seen few applications where the architect decided to keep the business logic separate from data, thus database only has the data and no PL/SQL programming involved.

Comment: Yes, I too have seen such terrible things. Although how they think you can separate all the business logic from the database layer is beyond me. After all, constraints are part of the business logic. Unless, I suppose, they don't care about the validity of their data, in which case, I would suggest a database pointing to /dev/null... *{;-)